# Does the set $H=\{1,4,7,13\}$ with modulo $15$ multiplication, $\otimes_{15}$, create a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

> Does the set $H=\{1,4,7,13\}$ with modulo $15$ multiplication, $\otimes_{15}$, create a group?

$$\begin{array}{|r|c|c|c|} 
\hline
\otimes_{15}  & 1 & 4 & 7 & 13\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 4 & 7 & 13\\ \hline
4 & 4 & 1 & 13 & 7\\ \hline
7 & 7 & 13 & 4 & 1\\ \hline
13 & 13 & 7 & 1 & 4\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I learned that I have to make a table. What can I read from it?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: $H$ is the subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^*$ generated by $7$ or $13$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to verify the axioms of the definition of a group for $\mathscr{H}=(H, \otimes_{15}).$

The set $H$ is closed under $\otimes_{15}$ by inspection of the multiplication table. (It satisfies the Latin square property.)

The identity is $1$.

The inverse of $4$ is itself. The inverse of $7$ is $13$ and *vice versa*.

Associativity of $\otimes_{15}$ is inherited from that of ordinary multiplication.

Hence $\mathscr{H}$ is a group.

Comment: is there a different approach to this task without using the table?

Comment: @vmahth1:  see my answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is the subgroup of the group of units modulo $15$ that is generated by $7$ (or $13$).